# Comparing and highlighting Columns 18 and 20

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting an error on the "If Report.Cells(i,18).Value <> "" Then line. I know I must be missing something silly here...

Just trying to compare columns 18 and 20 and highlight differences.

I know this can be done other ways as well...

```
Sub Compare_Columns()

    'Get the last row
    Dim Report As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    'Set Report = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'You could also use Excel.ActiveSheet if you always want this to run on the current sheet.
    Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet

    lastRow = Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        For j = 2 To lastRow
            If Report.Cells(i, 18).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
                If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 20).Value, Report.Cells(i, 18).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                    Report.Cells(i, 18).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White background
                    Report.Cells(i, 18).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Report.Cells(i, 18).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                    Report.Cells(i, 18).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'Now I use the same code for the second column, and just switch the column numbers.
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        For j = 2 To lastRow
            If Report.Cells(i, 20).Value <> "" Then
                If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 18).Value, Report.Cells(i, 20).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Report.Cells(i, 20).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White background
                    Report.Cells(i, 20).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Report.Cells(i, 20).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                    Report.Cells(i, 20).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Code compiles and runs fine for me, but I don't have your data.  If there is a cell in your range that evaluates to an error, like "#REF" or "#DIV/0" then this will certainly trip the macro.  To avoid this, you could test the cell using IF ISERROR(report.cells(i,20).value) then...

Comment: Works fine here as well. The only reason it wouldnt work fine is as mentioned above. If you have a formula that gives a #REF, #DIV, #N/A, this will return an error.

Comment: Thanks guys...that makes sense. It was because I had #N/A in some of the rows.